# Identifying Robert Chichester listed amongst British Guiana Colonists?

Tags: 19th-century, indexing, guyana

[British Guiana Colonists](http://www.vc.id.au/tb/index.html) is an

> index of 18th and 19th century residents of the colonies of Berbice,
>   Demerara, and Essequebo ... compiled and maintained by Tikwis Begbie
>   from a wide variety of sources.

On its [British Guiana Colonists Index "C"](http://www.vc.id.au/tb/bgcolonistsC.html) page (from which the above quote comes) it has an entry that is of interest to me:

> CHICHESTER, Robert

All the other CHICHESTER entries there appear to be closely related to my 4th great grandfather Robert Chichester (and can be found in other questions on this site):

- CHICHESTER, James was his nephew (son of his brother Giles)
- CHICHESTER, Jared was his son
- CHICHESTER, Maria Dorothea was his daughter-in-law (wife of his son Jared)
- CHICHESTER, Thomas was his son
- CHICHESTER, William was his brother

However, I have no evidence that Robert himself ever visited British Guiana.

Does anyone know the source for the name "CHICHESTER, Robert" appearing in this index?

If I can track that, then maybe I can establish his identity as being that of my ancestor, or of another Robert Chichester.

I have been unable to find contact information for the author of the site (Tikwis Begbie), and so a simple email is not yet possible. I have searched [Guyana Colonial Newspapers](http://vc.id.au/edg/) without success.

Comment: I can't help with the Chichesters, I'm afraid, but [this blog](http://jonoguyana.blogspot.co.uk/2006/01/british-guiana-colonists.html) links to an old (and broken) version of the colonists website. It does have an email address for Tikwis Begbie, though. A quick search shows she's used that email address elsewhere, but perhaps not for a few years. It may still be active and worth a try.   Failing that, have you contacted the current site maintainer (Rodney van Cooten)? There's a link at the bottom of the home page, which I'm sure wasn't there last time I looked.

Comment: THanks @AndyW I have just emailed Tikwis and Rodney, following your advice, and my fingers are crossed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now made contact with Tikwis Begbie who has sent me the notes held offline from the site on the name Chichester.

From those it appears that the Robert Chichester mentioned on the site is my 4th great grandfather, but he is mentioned there, not because any evidence places him in British Guiana, but instead because he is recorded as being the father of Jared and Thomas Chichester.  The presence of these two sons of Robert in British Guiana is supported by several documents.

Comment: Great! I'm glad to hear that site is still supported. I have a great-great-uncle who married in Guyana in the 1890s, and I may try to find out more.